# node.js cant parse from a loop

Tags: node.js, parsing

I have an array of json formatted string. I wants to parse it in a loop . its not parsing in that loop. After first element, its giving and error of unexpected token.

eg:

```
Array[{"id":10}, {"id":10}, {"id":10}, {"id":10}, {"id":10}]
for(var i:Number=0; i<Array.length; i++)
{
 // passing each json string to function
 main_function(Array[i]);
}

function main_function(data)
{
try{
var jsn= JSON.parse(data);
}catch(err)
{
}
}
```

this giving unexpected token error message. What could be the fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first line of code needs to define an array and assign that to a actual variable and your `for` loop can then refer to that variable.  There's also no point in calling `JSON.parse()` on data that is already a Javascript object.  `JSON.parse()` is used to convert JSON strings into Javascript objects.  It does not do anything when you pass it something is already a Javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to do here. But if you want to do something with each object (in your case, 5 objects with a property `id` with a value of `10`) you can simply do:

```
var myArray = [{"id":10}, {"id":10}, {"id":10}, {"id":10}, {"id":10}];
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
 // passing each object to your main data function
 main_function(myArray[i]);
}

function main_function(data)
{
  console.log(data.id);
}
```

You don't need `JSON.parse` since your array is already composed of objects. You use `JSON.parse` when what you are receiving is a string, not directly an object array. For example if what you had was:

```
var arrayAsAJSONString = "[{\"id\":10}, {\"id\":10}, {\"id\":10}, {\"id\":10}, {\"id\":10}]";
```

You would do:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(arrayAsAJSONString);
// rest of the code exactly the same
```

Comment: The array values might be different. I want to do parsing in a loop or like a stream.

Comment: @user2393848 whether you need to do "parsing" depends on what values you have in your array, but we can't figure anything out if you don't specify it in the question